# What is 'User cannot suggest edits to this question'?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, android-app

I recently came across a poorly written question and thought of suggesting some edits to correct some spellings, mathjax and format it for a better look.
But, after I was completed and clicked on suggest edits, this is what I came across:

[image]

Couldn't understand what and why this was? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306610/271002

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in [the post Loong linked to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306610/312770), the likely reason why you cannot suggest an edit is because there is already a pending suggested edit. The suggested edit has to be approved/rejected before you can suggest another edit.

See also: [Why is the edit button disabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81681/312770)